# Importing Data using joins; more than one row returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join, sql-insert

Im trying to move data from a source table to a Master table. my source table has a category, but no ID. I need to take the category name from the source table, join it to the category table, and insert that ID into my target table.

Here is what I am working with so far (SQL Server):

```
Select C_CATID, C_CategoryDesc, b.Record_No (using this to differentiate records, as i keep getting duplicates) from [Category_Tree_Lookup]

inner join [dbo].[TBL_C_Mapped SpendData_12_2014OLD03312015] b 
    on C_categorydescription = b.category

where C_CategoryDesc = b.category
```

I keep receiving too many records that are duplicates, so i cannot insert into the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the table structures and some sample data? sqlfiddle.com would be a good place to do this. As posted there is not a lot of information here.

Comment: I added the Table structure to sql fiddle here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6684e

Comment: Having some data and expected output would be helpful here. Also, why are you using floats in one table and ints in the other???

Comment: The source table was given to me from someone who doesn't create or work with databases. It's not something I could correct so I am making due, lol.

Comment: OK, but where is the sample data?

Comment: I added a sample row for each. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: You didn't post an updated link. Also, if the problem is that you are getting more than 1 row returned it would be a bit helpful if you had more than 1 row in the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct function like this

```
select distinct C_CATID, C_CategoryDesc, b.Record_No from tablename
```

Comment: The issue after that becomes inserting these category IDs (many have the same ID) into the target table. I have no way of distinguishing how to do this?